# Matplotlib x-axis overcrowded label rendering

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to simply plot a numpy array but I'm having troubles, especially with getting the number of ticks and labels right on the x-axis.

I'm dealing with an array named percents that looks like this:

```
percents:

-74    0.000041
-61    0.000041
-60    0.000041
-59    0.000041
-57    0.000041
...
 71    0.000041
 73    0.000041
 75    0.000041
 77    0.000041
 80    0.000081
```

The range of the index is from -74 to 80 and the values themselves are from near 0 to a high of 70 (occurs around indexes near zero).

When I simply plot this array using Seaborn barplots, I get a nightmare on the x-axis.

```
categ = percents.index.tolist()
vals = percents.values.tolist()

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

sns.barplot(categ, vals)
```

[image]

Wanting to perhaps use `xticks` to solve this, I tried adding this code, which makes it even worse, actually:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(-80,80,10), np.arange(-80,80,10))
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Seaborn does its axes a bit differently. Your solution works if you call plt.bar() instead. It looks like instead of doing it based on data range (ie -80 to 80), it's from 0 to 160. 
This works for me (with a Seaborn plot):

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 160, 10), np.arange(-80, 80, 10))
```

Comment: I would also use `plt.bar` here.

Comment: Resetting the major locator to http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.AutoLocator and http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter is probably the second best solution after just using `ax.bar`.  Under the hood `plt.xticks` is setting both the locator and formatter to the Fixed varieties of both which is less than great for interactivity.  It also scares me a bit to have the ticks de-coupled from the data space units with numeric labels.